# Compilation error for Regex using JS223 Groovy script

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to use Groovy Script in a JS223 Post Processor to return "Town" and "Sacramento Document Repository" from the string below:

```
documentRepository|Town\|Sacramento Document Repository|A58D876A581D6A4F297703D9EA443775
```

I've tested the following two pieces of regex in https://regex101.com/ and they work perfectly:

```
\|(.+?)\\ - returns "Town"
\\\|(.+?)\| - returns "Sacramento Document Repository"
```

However compilation is failing for two regexes in the JS223 processor:

```
String REGEX1 = "\|(.+?)\\";
String REGEX2 = "\\\|(.+?)\|";
```

Error I'm getting back is:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script85.groovy: 10: unexpected char: '\' @ line 10, column 17.
   String REGEX = "\|(.+?)\\";
```

I suspect the issue is to do with escaping the backslashes. Can someone please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the [meta characteres](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) in regular expressions, to wit change this:

```
\|(.+?)\\
```

to this:

```
\\|(.+?)\\\\
```

Also you can use Groovy's [Find Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html) and a little bit less scary syntax.

Something like:

```
def source = 'documentRepository|Town\\|Sacramento Document Repository|A58D876A581D6A4F297703D9EA443775'

def matches = (source =~ '(?<=\\|)[^|]*(?=\\|)')
def town = matches[0]
def sacramento = matches[1]

log.info('Town: ' + town)
log.info('Sacramento: ' + sacramento)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Pattern Matching in Strings in Groovy](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-pattern-matching)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Spot on again! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax:

```
 Pattern myRegex = ~/regex/
```

described in this article:

- https://regular-expressions.mobi/groovy.html?wlr=1

This will not require any escaping as it’s one of groovy way of delimiting strings made for regex.

Ensure you import package:

```
 import java.util.regex.*
```